# Javascript Autocomplete - Hide and Show Div

Tags: javascript, css

I currently have a working code for Javascript autocomplete, which redirects the user to a certain webpage depending on what they type into an input field.

However I'm trying to acomplsih a feature where one div is hidden and one div appears depending on what they type into an input field.

For example, if they typed Spencer Kline into an input box, I want 'div1' to disappear and 'div2' to appear.

I currently have this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        label: "Spencer Kline"
      }, {
        value: "www.example.com",
        label: "James Bond"
      }

    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
      window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
  });
});
</script>      
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" style="width: 75%;">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are div1 and div2 on the current page or on www.foo.com / www.example.com ?

Comment: They are on the current page.

Comment: Your post is not all that clear unfortunately. Just to try and make things more clear... do you want the div to change on after the user has SELECTED 'Spencer Kline' or as they are typing in? Currently when that value is selected it redirects so I presume it should be as they are typing 'Spencer Kline' into the box...?

Comment: then remove the redirection, delete windows.location.href = ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: [{
        value: "www.foo.com",
        label: "Spencer Kline"
      }, {
        value: "www.example.com",
        label: "James Bond"
      }

    ],
    select: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.item.label == "Spencer Kline") {
        $("#div1").show();
        $("#div2").hide(); // or whatever
      }
      window.location.href = ui.item.value;
    }
  });
});
```

But this makes no sense since we quit the current page with `window.location.href = ui.item.value;` .

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want the user to be re-directed - I'll try your solution.

Comment: just check my edit I made a mistake in the first place

Comment: Cheers, this has resolved my problem! I've + 1 and marked it as the answer :)

Comment: Yeah, the trick is to have ths good selector before the .hide() . Maybe you could add a certain class (for instance "closable") to every div you want to hide if Kline is selected, then just write $(".closable").hide();

Answer (score 0):

So just for demonstration I have added in two divs for you.

As you've mentioned you don't want them to be redirected on the select... so you have to check to see what the values of the labels are, and if they match a criteria, just use JQuery to manipulate the CSS of the div as shown below.

You can add your own css rules or styling to each div to hide or show them as you wish.

```
<html>
<head>

  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id = "div1">
    some div 1 content here...
  </div>

  <div id = "div2">
    some div 2 content here...
  </div>

  <input type="text" id="autocomplete" style="width: 75%;">
</body>

</html>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({

      source : [{
          value : "www.foo.com",
          label : "Spencer Kline"
        }, 
        {
          value : "www.example.com",
          label : "James Bond"
        }],
      select: function(event, ui) {

        if(ui.item.label === "Spencer Kline"){

          $("#div1").css("display", 'none');

        }

      }

    });

  });
</script>
```